# Failed to convert 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicSettings' to type 'System.String'

Tags: tfs

I am getting this error when my TFS workflow hits the Run On Agent initialization. I tried to revert back the recent changes where I added new variable to the workflow and initialized it, but later I removed it but no  luck.\

> Run On Agent Exception System.Xaml.XamlObjectReaderException: Failed to convert 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicSettings' to type 'System.String'. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Reflection.AssemblySignatureKeyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Comment: provide some code pls

Comment: can you please put some code for reference to your issue.

Comment: All the default built in activities no extra code added. Build error just shown, not even the stack trace is given, so its bit difficult to locate the issue. I have chosen the diagnostic as verbosity but then also not getting the error stack. Is there any way I can get the more details about the error.

Comment: Found the following exception, any clues regarding this exception.

Comment: Run On Agent Exception System.Xaml.XamlObjectReaderException: Failed to convert 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicSettings' to type 'System.String'. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Reflection.AssemblySignatureKeyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: This issue was due new 4.5 framework installation and after machine restart issue got resolved.

Comment: Issue resolved by restarting the build server after the. Net framework 4.5 installation